# Azure DevOps - Shared Test Steps Across Organizations

Tags: azure-devops

So I can see that in Azure Test Plans you can create shared test steps, and these can be used in different test plans, different test suites, and even different projects within the organization. But is there any way to use the shared steps from a different organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps - Shared Test Steps Across Organizations

I am afraid there is no such way to use shared test steps across organization at this moment.

When we insert a shared test step, there is option that we could only **Query across projects** but not Organizations:

[image]

Besides, as we know the shared test step is a work item, we could use the option **Move to team project** to move it to other project but not Organizations:

[image]

Hope this helps.